# Dialog Fragment's first view focused twice while accessibility enabled

Tags: android, accessibility, android-dialogfragment, dialogfragment, talkback

I am opening a `dialogFragment` (without toolbar) from `fragment` class. When this dialogFragment appears, `Talkback accessibility focus` on the first element of my view reflecting twice.

It reads out the `contentDescription` for the first view with `importantForAccessibility = yes` two times.

I am aware that android talkback treats dialogFragment differently than fragments. Is this natural behavior of dialogFragments in case of accessibility?

Comment: Are you forcing a focus on the first element? Since in `Dialog`s the screen reader announce the first element, if you force a focus on it, it will read twice.

Comment: @DiegoMalone Nope.. It initiate naturally.

Comment: This looks like a Talkback bug. Can you add some more details about the first view and the overall XML so I can repro. And what version of Talkback are you using?

Comment: having this issue now. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @JoelDean Nope, not yet. Can you please let me know if you find some relatable things to it?

Comment: @ShailenTuli Sorry, I missed your comment. 
It's just a simple XML file with RelativeLayout. and my first view is ImageView 
Can you please let me know how can I fetch the talkback version? I think that will depend on the mobile device.

Comment: @DharaVamja , did you any solution on this ? , What I experience that in absence of Title , it is announcing twice . If we set blank string , this will fix .

Comment: But when dialog is resumed from background , blank string title will not work... still figuring out , How Talkback get dynamic title ?

Answer (score 4):

Did you try calling setTitle on the dialog?
If you didn't set a title, Talkback might consider your first focusable element as the title, and read it twice - once the the title, and once as the first element.

Comment: That does make sense.. Thank you!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Dialog has a title, and unless you set one specifically talkback sets the title as the content description of the first element inside de dialog.
To avoid this I changed the title with dialog.setTitle("new title").

Note: setting null or empty string as the title doesn't fix the issue